# "/" character on first line remove all text with JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i want to generate a report using JRDesignTextField,
when my html text starts with "/" character in the exportation (xls or pdf) the text is all deleted !

example `/BNF/XYC/ABCdddd<br/> XzC`      => result in .xls (excel) : `XzC`

```
 textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    textField.setBlankWhenNull(true);
    textField.setStretchWithOverflow(true);
    textField.setMarkup(JRCommonText.MARKUP_HTML);
   ....
```

Comment: Consider closing question, by accepting answer or passing your own answer  if you consider that problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Escape `/` with `&#92;` so that your String is

```
&#92;BNF&#92;XYC<br/> XzC
```

**EDIT**: Concatenation of `<p></p>` will also work

```
<p>/BNF/XYZ<br/> XzC</p>
```

and remember to `setMarkup(JRCommonText.MARKUP_HTML)` on the `JRDesignTextField`

Comment: can i concat <p></p> to the textfield to prevent this kind of problem ?
example : JRDesignTextField
/BNF/XYC<br/> XzC will be <p>/BNF/XYC<br/> XzC</p>  and  setMarkup(JRCommonText.MARKUP_HTML)

Comment: Yes that should also work. I updated my answer to included it.